# Writing array elements into different file

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have array of array that looks like this

```
var data=[["snp","3569#maspd"],["kpr","ant#$casd"]];
```

What I want to do is to write this data to a file according to length of the [1]element.

For example, let's take first element in array (which is also an array)

```
["snp","3569#maspd"]
```

[1] element `3569#maspd` is 10 characters long= `length=10`, so data from this array will be written into file "10.txt"

I have written a code for it

```
var result=cont.split("\n").
                map(function(r){return r.split(",").slice(2,4);//.join(":")
            }) //this creates array of arrays


    result.forEach(function(x){
        var length=x[1].length;
        var str=length.toString();


        var fil=length+".txt";
        var txt=x.join(":");
        fs.exists(fil,function(exist){
            if(exist){
                fs.appendFile(fil,txt,function(err){
                    if(err) console.log(err)
                })
            }
            else{
                fs.writeFile(fil,txt,function(err){
                    if(err) console.log(err)
                })
            }
        })

    }

    )
```

But it always throws an error "cannot read property length of undefined". When I remove all code and leave only

```
result.forEach(function(x){
    var length=x[1].length;
    var str=length.toString();
        console.log(str)
}
)
```

It works, did I overlook an bug here?
here is an example value of what  result array looks like (with random data)

```
var result=[[ '62346asd5f5510dda8f6223c557bb0bf0b5',
  'MH))WXlhs\'uOSu.iwJk[n}oz#w>T6L' ],
[ '00d7994173ds265bfe71182154a1143b0', '&Df1' ],
[ '1b6c32941719fcbfc76c6e5428e5f5',
  'Fc/0PG#mHb49&#)V|$Swrr7as_*UnL~Y' ],
[ 'f931c2256eca136c97a9a9af4dcae', '.a=]' ]]
```

Comment: Please show us an example value for cont that would reproduce what you're describing.

Comment: added it to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check/sanitize your input and make sure that `x` has 2 item.

A basic way to do this could be changing from

```
var length=x[1].length;
```

to something like

```
var length= x[1] != undefined ? x[1].length : 0;
```

A better way could be [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) you array data to make sure it's safe.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is in your result array.  You most likely have bad data coming in or a problem with your map function. Run the code below with your sample data and it works fine.   You can add a try catch to skip it or log it out so you can see the line causing the problem.

```
fs = require('fs');

var data=[
            [ '62346asd5f5510dda8f6223c557bb0bf0b5',
              'MH))WXlhs\'uOSu.iwJk[n}oz#w>T6L' ],
            [ '00d7994173ds265bfe71182154a1143b0', 
              '&Df1' ],
            [ '1b6c32941719fcbfc76c6e5428e5f5',
              'Fc/0PG#mHb49&#)V|$Swrr7as_*UnL~Y' ],
            [ 'f931c2256eca136c97a9a9af4dcae', 
              '.a=]' ]
         ];

data.forEach(function(x){
    var length= x[1].length;
    var str=length.toString();


    var fil=length+".txt";
    var txt=x.join(":");
    fs.exists(fil,function(exist){
        if(exist){
            fs.appendFile(fil,txt,function(err){
                if(err) console.log(err)
            })
        }
        else{
            fs.writeFile(fil,txt,function(err){
                if(err) console.log(err)
            })
        }
    })

});
```